# How to handle the view controllers?

Tags: iphone, controller, navigation, tabbar

Hi guys I am working on an application.Where there is a home screen with 5 buttons.On the click of every button i want to open the screen with tabbar with 5 view controllers.I mean when you click on the button the tabbar is opened.And there are back button on the tab bar view as well .On clicking the back button i want to pop back to the home screen and vice versa.
How to do that guys.Any tutorial ,links,sample code would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot to all

Comment: Zoozoo, there is a home screen with navigation controller having 5 buttons, on the click of any button i want to open the application in tab based like having 4 tabs.Now when the tab views come there needs to be a back button there and clicking that i want to navigate back to the home screen of buttons.Did you get me now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tabbar controller in a navigation stack is complicated. Since each tab controller can have also navigation controller itself.

Have a `WindowManager` class. It should own both 
   - `FirstViewController` and 
   - `TabbarController`

All components and the UITabbarControllers themselves should be instantiated in the WindowManager class. 
Its `init` may have code like this, make similar for two tabbarcontrollers.

```
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.controllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// initialize the view controllers and navigation controllers for the tab bar

self.friendsVC = [[FriendsVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"FriendsView" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *friendsNVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: friendsVC];
friendsNVC.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
[controllers addObject:friendsNVC];  
[friendsNVC release];

self.paymentsVC = [[PaymentsVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"PaymentsView" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *paymentsNVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: paymentsVC];
paymentsNVC.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
[controllers addObject:paymentsNVC];
[paymentsNVC release];  

tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0; 
tabBarController.delegate = self;

self.view = tabBarController.view;
```

In the `WindowManager`, you can have two methods like,

```
[WindowManager showViewController] and
[WindowManager showTabbarController].

- showViewController {
  //Initiate View controller and use [self.window addSubView:vc.view];
}

- showTabbarController {
  // initiate the tabbar manager
}
```

You can have a "back" button on top of your first tabbar controller left side, to call the

```
[WindowManager showViewController];
```

Comment: Hey karim thaks for your answer i have tried this way,but the problem occurs when i want to pop to the main screen ,it doesn't pop.Firstly i took the homeviewcontroller with navigationcontroller,then i push it to the tabbar view, but when i click on the back button on the tab bar it doesnt pop to the home view.Do you have any idea how to pop to the home view then.I tried calling [self.navigationcontroller poptoviewcontroller:YES]; and   [self.navigationcontroller.tabbarcontroller poptoviewcontroller:YES];  as well

Comment: Having tab bar controller in a navigation stack is undesired and discouraged. I have edited the answer more elaborately to do the same.

Comment: Yes I know that is not the good approach ,and then the stack organization would not be good.But what could i do the client wants in that way.I told the T.L. that it can't be done this way, either it needs to be tab based or navigation based.

Comment: Fine i Will give try to this....................  And what do you mean by the window manager class is this the application delegate class or i can take anyview controller class for this

Comment: @Karim thanks it worked for me.I gave it a shot.But i think that would create a problem in the memory management as the stack will continue to increase.So i am going to use the custom home view for every tab bar view which i will call every time on the back button.Thanks

Comment: WindowManager is custom class. You have to write it. in each of the method, when you call them, clean the memory. release view controller/tabbar controller. I mentioned earlier, both view and tabbar controller should be owned by the WindowManager class.